# Splitting a sorted lazy frame into smaller chunks, preserving whole groups

Tags: python-polars

I need to split a multi-GB file that I am intending to add more ML-features to (adding lead and lag features). Without splitting the file, I am running out of ram, even in lazy mode.

The data is sorted by the first column, which is an `id` column that always contains 13 consecutive entries of the same value. It is important to avoid splitting the group of ids into separate files. This means we could split the file at every 13th, 26th, 39th (etc) position and preserve the whole group of `id`s.

Ideally, I'd like each file to end up being ~100MB in size. The actual `df.shape` is `(5965869, 193)`, and assuming each column has a size of 8 byte, that means that I would need to split it into approximately files of 5000*13 rows.

I could get the first chunk using `df.limit(5000*13)`, but I'm unsure on how to proceed after that. I also don't know how I would deal with the potential case where each file would contain N rows, but the last file contains fewer rows, since the total row count may not evenly divide into N, but leave a remainder.

The following is a minimal example of 13*20 = 260 rows. How could I split this into 3 files - where the first two files have 13*8 rows each, and the last takes the remaining 13*4 rows?

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({"id":13*list(range(20)), "value":np.arange(13*20)}).sort(by="id")
ldf = df.lazy()

# Either via groupby somehow
ldf.groupby("id")...take(...) # how to do this in a loop?

# or by reading the file in multiples of 13 rows
ldf...take_in_row_chunks(chunksize=some_multiple_of_13)
```

Comment: do you know how to split a dataframe in lazy mode? (like partition_by in lazy mode)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you are trying to split a dataframe into smaller chunks where each chunk contains 13 rows. As noted, you can partition by id where id by setting appropriate id. Something like:

```
df.with_row_count('id')
.with_column(pl.col('id')
.apply(lambda i: int(i/13)))
.partition_by('id')
```

Comment: is there a way to do this in lazy mode completely?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if i understand correctly the question but you want to split it each n rows into a new dataframe.

A possible approach would be to create a new id each 13th column and then split into the dataframes into a dictionary, for simplicity i will use a split each n numbers in order for it to be reproducible. I apologize for not knowing how to insert code here in advance.

```py
    import math
    
    df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "foo": ["A", "A", "B", "B", "C","C","a"],
            "N": [1, 2, 2, 4, 2,3,3],
            "bar": ["k", "l", "m", "m", "l","o","v"],
        }
    )
    
    a = df.height # number of rows
    n = 3  # split each rows
    b = (np.linspace(1, math.ceil(a/n), num=math.ceil(a/n)))
    c = (np.repeat(b, n))[:-( n - (a%n))]
    df = df.lazy().with_column(pl.lit(c).alias('new_index')).collect()
    m = df.partition_by(groups="new_index", maintain_order=True, as_dict=True)
```

result will be a dictionary where key is the n number of the split.

Answer (score 0):

Due to some of the function being deprecated, I find it such that this is the best method right now.

```py
# create a column with 13 different ids
partitions = data.with_row_count("id").select(pl.col("id") // 13)
# group based on the created id, resulting 13 partitons
data_partitioned = data.with_columns(partitions).partition_by("id")
```

Answer (score 0):

### LazyFrame

First, you should set the `streaming` parameter to `True` when calling [`collect()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/lazyframe/api/polars.LazyFrame.collect.html).

> **streaming**
>
> Process the query in batches to handle larger-than-memory data. If set to False (default), the entire query is processed in a single batch.

Secondly, it might be useful to specify the chunk size that this streaming engine will use, as you might be in a situation where it is too optimistic.
According to [polars.Config.set_streaming_chunk_size](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_streaming_chunk_size.html#polars.Config.set_streaming_chunk_size) :

> By default, the chunk size is determined by the schema and size of the thread pool. For some datasets (esp. when you have large string elements) this can be too optimistic and lead to Out of Memory errors.

So, enlarging a bit your example, it would give something like

```
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({"id":13*list(range(2000000)), "value":np.arange(13*2000000)}).sort(by="id")

ldf = df.lazy()

# tweak the streaming engine chunk_size
pl.Config.set_streaming_chunk_size(5000*13)

ldf.collect(streaming=True)
# shape: (26_000_000, 2)

ldf.select("value").collect(streaming=True).sum()
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ value           │
│ ---             │
│ i64             │
╞═════════════════╡
│ 337999987000000 │
└─────────────────┘
```

Note that the `streaming` parameter is currently tagged as alpha.

### DataFrame

Then, once collected with/without the `engine`, if you still need to work with multiple small datasets, you can choose among regular DataFrame manipulation functions:

- [`partition_by`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.partition_by.html) will chunk based on a column value
- [`iter_slices`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.iter_slices.html) will chunk based on a number of rows (more likely your case)